# Upload Image in Crystal Report without Saving image in DB in ASP.NEt using C#

Tags: c#, asp.net, crystal-reports

I have an Asp.Net using C# Application in which I have Saved the Bar Code Image in DB in Blob format and fetched that in Crystal Report and it is working fine till now.

But According to our DBA it is eating up lots of DB space so they have informed me to change the Application.

So Now instead of Saving the Image in DB I have to Save the Image in a Folder and then Call it in the Crystal Report Dynamically, as I will be saving the path of image in DB.

Have Searched Google But Didn't get any solution.

Please if you have any solution or Example please Help me to Solve this issue.

Thanks a Lot in Advance...

Comment: What exactly is the problem, the solution (store as file) sounds fine. What path are you storing? You might need a url, not a filesystem path.

Comment: I am saving a image file in a folder and the path to that image in the database.
So Now I want to Fetch This image which is saved in the folder to be displayed in the crystal report dynamically using the image path which is saved in the database.

Fetching Image from DB was Simple, But I am not getting any solution for this, Even searched Whole Google and many Forums...

Answer (score 0):

Got Solution to my Problem:
Pls Refer : http://csharpdotnetfreak.blogspot.com/2012/06/crystal-reports-display-images-database.html if anyone need the Solution.